# Once I compare two tables how can I update the first table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Once I have the two tables compared and they give me what has changed, I would like the first table to be updated with the new data from the second one.

This is my code where I put in my phpmyadmin database that compares the two tables:

```sql
SELECT 
   codice_Fiscale,nome,cognome,etichetta,sesso,residenza,
   cellulare,email,telefono,id_vitaever
FROM ( 
    SELECT codice_Fiscale,nome,cognome,etichetta,sesso,residenza,
           cellulare,email,telefono,id_vitaever 
    FROM operatore
    UNION ALL
    SELECT codice_Fiscale,nome,cognome,etichetta,sesso,residenza,
           cellulare,email,telefono,id_vitaever 
    FROM operatoreImport
) tbl
GROUP BY codice_Fiscale,nome,cognome,etichetta,sesso,residenza,
    cellulare,email,telefono,id_vitaever
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY codice_Fiscale
```

I have this tables:

TABLE 1:
id name
1  Oriol
2  Ricard

TABLE 2:
id name
1  Uriol
2  Ricard

And once compared the two tables, I want this:

TABLE 1:
id name
1  Uriol
2  Ricard

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Where did `Oriol` go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this code help you

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 
SET t1.name=t2.name, t1.surname=t2.surname
WHERE t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB

Comment: Thanks Mike now is runnung all!